# How do I read in files to a 2D array regardless of whether they're space or newline-delimited in java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have some input files that are made up of integers. Some of these input files' numbers are organized by one line, separated by spaces.

`1    2    3    4    5    6...`

Others are organized in line breaks.

`1
2
3
4
5
6
...`

What I want to do is read in every file in that directory of files, and store each file in a 2D array wherein they can be sorted. In this sample code, `fileArr` is the array of files which holds all of the files from the directory in question. `nums` is the 2D array I'm trying to store it in, with the first bracket (`nums[]`) representing the file and the second array (`nums[][]`) representing the data found within. `line` is a string array. The code below is the closest I've come to having it work. The code works when the data is all stored in one line, as in the first example, but what happens in the second one is that each individual line generates a single-element array `line` with that line's number in it, such that `nums[i][q]` only ends up being one element.

```
    // Below is a code that reads all of the raw data into a 2D array
    int[][] nums = new int[fileArr.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < fileArr.length; i++) {
        fileRead = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileArr[i])));

        while (fileRead.hasNextLine() != false) {
            line = fileRead.nextLine().trim().split("\\s+");
        }
        nums[i] = new int[line.length];
        for (int q = 0; q < line.length; q++) {
            nums[i][q] = Integer.parseInt(line[q]);
        }
    }
    // end block
```

I hope I explained that well. Basically, I just to be able to store data from a file in a 2D array regardless of whether those numbers are stored vertically (newlines) or horizontally (whitespace).

Comment: In the case of the file with numbers separated by newlines, how would you know where a given logical row ends?  That is, how do you know how many lines to read?  The thing is, with the first version of the file, you actually have _two_ markers, the spaces in between each number, and the newline at the end of each line.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen As specified each file only contains single dimensional data. The second dimension in this case is specified to be the index of the file, not anything related to the formatting of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `next()` instead of `nextLine()` - here's an example application that prints all "words" separate by any whitespace, whether that be spaces or newlines from the input:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader (System.in)));
    for(;;) {
      System.out.println(in.next());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I appreciate the insight (it hadn't occurred to me that `.next` would help with this issue), but I'm having trouble understanding how to apply it to my specific scenario. `line` is basically a temp string array which stores the values as strings, and then reads those values as integers to `nums`. I don't know how to use `.next` because I don't know how to define the size of the array without, for example, either finding the int length of the file and using that, or doing what I did above, directly splitting into the array `line = fileRead.nextLine().trim().split("\\s+");`

Comment: Earlier in the code, `line` is just initialized as `String[] line;` I want to intialize first, and the define once I figure out the size of what I'm trying to store into the array.

Comment: @CelineDion Just use an `ArrayList` instead of a a plain array for now, then you don't need to worry about setting the right size. Everything else is either going to involve implementing what array list does or parsing the entire file and then adding the array